# Passing an object(control) in session from one page to another

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, session-variables, infragistics

I need to pass a Infragistics ultrawebtree from a page to another. I used Session("data") for this and then I just access it from another page. But when  I assign the session value after casting to a Infragistics ultrawebtree control in my second page, it doesnot build the tree structure and it is invisibile. Is I am wroung in this approach, is there any other way to pass the entire tree structure from one page and display it into another page. Any help is appreciated

Comment: how can i pass the tree structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything, I would store the datasource in session instead of the tree. Storing the entire control in session creates a lot of unnecessary overhead, and limits your options per implementation on the next page.

**EDIT**: You should be able to export the tree structure to XML format, and store the XML in session. According to the documentation there should be `WriteXmlDoc()` and `WriteXmlString()` functions available. There's also `ReadXmlDoc()` and `ReadXmlString()` functions you can use to repopulate the tree on the next page.

Here's the [documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.v11.1~Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.UltraWebTree_members.html) for the UltraWebTree. You'll see these methods under the Public Methods section:

Comment: It is a tree , we are adding nodes by nodes instead of setting the datasource. So I cannot pass the datasource as session

Comment: the problem is tree is not rendering after I assign the session value after casting.

Comment: Are you redirecting right after committing it to session, by any chance?

Comment: No Actually i need to load the same tree in a pop up which was created using Iframe. So that I can avoid recurssive function calls to construct the tree structure if this can be implemented.

Comment: but this also needs some function to recreate the tree structure in another page

Comment: Are you talking about the XML solution? There's a `ReadXmlDoc` function too, which you can use to repopulate the tree on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Only the data should be stored in session.  Storing controls in session is likely to cause issues because the control will be disposed during page unload and controls shouldn't be accessed after being disposed which is what would happen when accessing the control from session.  See [Why Controls Shouldn't be Stored in Session](http://www.alhalama.com/blog/index.php?/archives/3-Why-Controls-Shouldnt-Be-Stored-In-Session.html) for more details.